# Microprogramming in MIPS

Tags: mips, cpu-architecture, microcoding

I am learning about micro programming and am confused as to what a micro-instruction actually is. I am using the MIPS architecture. My questions are as follows

Say for example I have the ADD instruction, what would the micro-instructions look like for this? How many micro-instructions are there for the add instruction. Is there somewhere online I can see the list of micro-instructions for the basic instructions of MIPS?

How can I figure out the bit string for an ADD microprogrammed instruction?

Answer (score 3):

[Microprogramming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microprogramming) is a method of implementing a complex instruction set architecture (such as x86) in terms of simpler "micro instructions". MIPS is a RISC instruction set architecture and is not typically implemented using micro-programming, so there are ZERO microinstructions for the ADD instruction.

To answer your specific question one would have to know what the definition of your particular micro-architecture is.

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of how to load the `EPC` into one of the registers and add 4-bytes to it:

```
lw      t0, 20(sp)      // Load EPC
addi    t0, 4           // Add 4 to the return adress
sw      t0, 20(sp)      // Save EPC
```

There are "a lot" of instructions that you can use, you can [see the MIPS Instruction Set here](http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html). In my humble opinion, MIPS is Really neat and easy to learn! A fun fact is that the first Playstation used a MIPS CPU.

**Example instructions**

- `lw` = load word
- `la` = load address
- `sw` = save word
- `addi` = add immidate

Then you have a lot of conditional instructions such as:

- `bne` = branch not equal
- `bnez` = branch not equal zero

And with these you use `j` to jump to an adress.

Here is an example from an Exception Handler that I wrote once for MIPS, this is the External Source handler:

```
External: 
        mfc0    t0, C0_CAUSE        // We could aswell use 24(sp) to load CAUSE
        and     t0, t0, 0x02000     // Mask the CAUSE
        bnez    t0, Puls            // If the only character left is 
                                    // "not equal zero" jump to Puls

        j   DisMiss                 // Else jump to DisMiss
```

In the above example I define an entry point called `External` that I can jump to, as I do with `DisMiss` to loop, you generally jump to yourself.

There are some other instructions used here aswell:

- `mfc0` = move from co-processor 0

To handle labels, [I would suggest you check this question/answer out.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4082341/mips-assembly-label-value-modification)

Here's a couple of resources on MicroProgramming with MIPS:

- [Some general information](http://www.student.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~cs251/general/microprog.html)
- [Here is a bit more heavy power-point presentation on the subject from Princton ( PDF )](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall04/cos471/lectures/09-Microcode.pdf)
- [Here is a paper](http://cmpe.emu.edu.tr/cergun/CMPE325/Microprogrammed%20Control%20Approach.pdf) from another university which is one of the best of these three ( PDF ).

Comment: I *think* he is asking about micro-programming, i.e. the micro-code for each instruction, rather than just basic assembly programming ?

Comment: Yes I am just asking specifically about micro-programming.

Comment: @microProgQuestions, have you looked at this: http://www.student.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~cs251/general/microprog.html ? @Paul, that's unfortunate for me.:)

Comment: @microProgQuestions, I've added a couple of resources that I find good/helpful, presentations and papers on the subject. I'll leave my initial answer as is, maybe someone will find it useful?

Comment: thank you for the links, I have seen the documentation you have posted, I just don't understand it. For example on the second link they have a table for R-type format instructions such as ADD, it has two rows though on below the which is blank which has a microinstruction of write. is this part of the R-type? Using this documentation how many micro-instructions are there for the r-type instructions (add) ?