# Assembly - How to multiply/divide a constant by another constant in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, constants, gnu-assembler, att

So, I have an assembly function, which is called in C. It compiles and gives me no warnings, but when I try to run it, it gives me a segmentation fault. I think it's because I can't move a constant into a register, but to use the mul/div command it requires a value to be in EAX register.
How can I multiply or divide two constants in Assembly?

Here's the code so far...

```
.section .data
.global n
.equ A, 50
.equ B, 5

.section .text
.global loop_function

loop_function:
    # prologue
    pushl %ebp      # save previous stack frame pointer
    movl %esp, %ebp  # the stack frame pointer for sum function
    # beginning 
    movl i, %ebx # place i (declared in c) in ebx
    movl A, %eax # place A in eax
    movl B, %ecx # place B in ecx
    jmp loop
loop:
    movl $0, %edx # clean edx register
    cdq
    idivl %ecx # A / B, result in eax
    imull %ebx # i * A / B, result in eax

    incl %ebx 
    cmpl %ebx, n # if i <= n
    jle loop # then jumps to loop
    jmp end # else jumps to end

end:
    # epilogue
    movl %ebp, %esp  #  restore the previous stack pointer ("clear" the stack)
    popl %ebp     #  restore the previous stack frame pointer
    ret
```

Comment: The real answer is in the [Application_binary_interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) (ABI). If you don't have the ABI, then I suggest pushing every register you use onto the stack, and popping it before returning.

Comment: The probable cause of error is that you are not following standard calling convention. In particular, you destroy `ebx` which is a callee-saved register and so your caller may very well expect it to be unchanged.

Comment: A and B seem to be constants and I'm guessing i is a variable, but you use the exact same syntax for all of them. I think it's trying to load values from memory address 50 and address 5, which isn't going to work. I suggest using $A and $B.

Comment: If I put $50 and $5 in the declaration of the constants, it fails the compilation, and $A gives the memory address of the constant, I think.

Comment: If I declare a global variable "xpto" and try to make an operation with it, "xpto" is the value stored in the variable, $xpto gives the memory address of that variable. I think it happens the same thing with constants.

Comment: You declared the constant as memory addresses, so you should use `$A` and `$B`. Have you tried it? To be able to use `A`, you need something like: `A: .int 50`.

Comment: Yes, that is a declaration of a global variable. I'm going to try $A and $B then.

Comment: @Jester: The syntax for assemble-time multiplication is less obvious than what I thought.  Turns out you need to leave out all but the first `$`, so it's `mov $(A * B), %eax`, otherwise you end up trying to reference a symbol called `$A` if you write `mov $($A * $B), %eax`

Answer (score 2):

GAS supports [the `*` operators for assemble-time multiplication](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Infix-Ops.html) of constants.  For example, `mov $(5 * 50), %eax` assembles to exactly the same machine code as `mov $250, %eax`.  Other operators like + - / %, and bitwise stuff are also available.  I'll just use `*` for the examples, but you can construct arbitrary expressions out of compile-time constants as long as they evaluate to a single number (or offset from a symbol that the linker can resolve).

This works with assembler constants like `.equ A, 50` or `A = 50` as well.

```
.equ A, 50
.equ B, 5

aa = 3
bb = 7

.globl _start
_start:                    # machine code         .intel_syntax disassembly
    mov $(5 * 50), %eax    # b8 fa 00 00 00    mov  eax,0xfa  # 250

    mov $(aa * B), %ecx    # b9 0f 00 00 00    mov  ecx,0xf   # 3*5 = 15
    mov $A * B,    %edx    # ba fa 00 00 00    mov  edx,0xfa  # 250
```

Note that the whole immediate constant only uses one `$`, rather than a `$` on every symbol name.  For example, `mov $(5 + $A), %eax` tries to put the address of a symbol called `$A` (plus 5) into `%eax`, so you get a link-time error for an undefined symbol.

`mov $( $A * $B ), %eax` doesn't even assemble:
`Error: invalid operands (*UND* and *UND* sections) for '*'`
This is because you're trying to multiply the address of two unknown symbols (`$A` and `$B`), rather than your assembler constants `A` and `B`.

In GAS, [all symbols have an associated *section*](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Arguments.html).  When you define a symbol with `.equ` or `=`, it's an "absolute" symbol (rather than a `.data` section or `.text` section symbol like you'd get from a label like `A:`).

Assembler constants aren't really different from symbols defined with labels.  However, other than `+` and `-`, all [assemble-time math operators require both args to be absolute, and the result is absolute](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Infix-Ops.html).

---

Your code appears to be trying to put the constants into registers to multiply them at runtime.  If you insist on doing that as an exercise,

```
mov   $A, %ecx           # put symbol's value in ECX
imul  $B, %ecx, %eax     # EAX = A * B
```

`mov A, %eax` is a load from the symbol's value.  i.e. a load from absolute address `50`, which obviously segfaults.  Single-step with a debugger and look at the disassembly to understand what happened.

AT&T syntax uses `$` for immediate constants, so use that to get the value.  (Remember, `.equ` symbols behave the same as labels, like how you'd use `$my_string` to get the address as an immediate.)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your help, guys, I managed to do the exercise with the following code:

```
.section .data
    .global n
    .global i
    .equ A, 50
    .equ B, 5

.section .text
    .global loop_function

loop_function:
    # prologue
    pushl %ebp      # save previous stack frame pointer
    movl %esp, %ebp  # the stack frame pointer for sum function
     # beginning 
    movl i, %ecx # place i (declared in c) in ecx
    movl $A, %eax  # place A in eax
    movl $B, %ebx # place B in ebx
    movl $0, %edx # clean edx register
    cdq
    idivl %ebx # (A / B), result goes to eax
loop:
    incl %ecx # increment i, which is in ecx
    cmpl n, %ecx # if n > i
    jg loop # then jumps to loop
end:
    incl %ecx
    imull %ecx # multiply i by (A / B), result in eax
    # epilogue
    movl %ebp, %esp  #  restore the previous stack pointer ("clear" the stack)
    popl %ebp     #  restore the previous stack frame pointer
    ret
```

Comment: You should pass `i` and `n` as function args instead of globals.  Also, `cdq` sets `edx` from `eax`, so there's no point in zeroing `edx` first.  Also, I don't see the point of the loop.  You could just replace it with `mov n, %ecx`.  (Or I guess with the extra `inc`, you're doing `%ecx = (n) + 1`)

Comment: Also, you clobber `%ebx` without saving it.  Use `%ecx` to hold `$B` for the idiv divisor.

Comment: So your whole function could be `mov $A, %eax` ; `cdq` ; `mov $B, %ecx` ; `idiv %ecx` ; `imul n, %eax`.  (Or load `n` into `ecx` or `edx` and then `inc %ecx` if it's actually `n+1` that you need).  You don't need to use the one-operand form, unless you want to return the full 64-bit product in `edx:eax`.  The 2-operand form is faster and only writes one register.)