# Assembly, x86: How to push a label to the stack?

Tags: assembly, x86, att, addressing-mode

given the data:

```
.section data
data_set:
.long 2,5,33,54,2,76,4,37,43,223,98,70,255
```

**how do I push the start address of the data (and not the value in that address) to the stack?**

I tried this:

```
pushl data_set
```

which eventually (after trying to access the data in this address) resulted in a segfault.

Comment: Did you try this out?

Comment: Why don't you try executing this code under a debugger and watch what happens?

Comment: @talz Try using a debugger to understand the control flow and see where the cde crashes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In AT&T syntax, to use an address as an immediate operand to an instruction, use `$label`.

**You want `pushl $data_set` for the `push imm32` instruction.**, like you would `push $123`.

`pushl data_set` would push a dword of data loaded from the address `data_set`, i.e.
`push m32`.

---

Conceptually, AT&T syntax treats everything as a potential address.  So `label` is an address, and so is `0x123`.  So `add 0x123, %eax` loads from the address `0x123`, and `add label, %eax` loads from the address `label`.  When you want a number as an immediate operand, you use `add $0x123, %eax`.  Using a symbol address as an immediate operand works identically.

Either way, the address is encoded into the instruction, it's just a question of whether it's as an immediate or as a displacement in an addressing mode.  This is why you use
`add $(foo - bar), %eax` to add the distance between two symbols, instead of
`add $foo-$bar, %eax` (which would look for a symbol called `$bar`, i.e. the `$` is part of the symbol name).  The `$` applies to the whole operand, not to symbol / label names.  Related: [more about assemble-time math in GAS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46869106/assembly-how-to-multiply-divide-a-constant-by-another-constant-in-assembly/46870205#46870205)

In other contexts, e.g. as an operand to `.long` or `.quad`, there's no immediate vs. memory operand issue, so you just write `dataptr: .long data_set` to emit 4 bytes of data holding the address of `data_set`, like you'd get from C `static int *dataptr = data_set;`

---

You could have checked on the syntax by looking at C compiler output for

```
void ext(int*);
static int data[] = {1,2,3};
void foo() {
    ext(data);
}
```

to get the C compiler to emit code passing a symbol address to a function.  I put this on [the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'void+ext(int*)%3B%0Astatic+int+data%5B%5D+%3D+%7B1,2,3%7D%3B%0Avoid+foo()+%7B%0A++++ext(data)%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:33.82165605095541,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g72,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-xc+-Wall+-O3+-m32',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+7.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),k:51.310184346245336,l:'4',m:68.53593568716833,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g72,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-xc+-O3+-Wall',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+7.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),k:48.68981565375467,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',m:70.48127497880414,n:'0',o:'',t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+gcc+7.2',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:29.51872502119587,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:66.17834394904459,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4), where it does indeed use `pushl $data`.

Comment: Technically `label` is always an address. The `$` just selects an instruction encoding with an immediate. E.g. if you wanted an immediate for the difference of two labels `foo` and `bar`, you'd do `$foo-bar` not `$foo-$bar` (which also happens to assemble without error, but references the symbols `foo` and `$bar`).

Comment: @Jester: Right thanks, rewrote my answer to get the concepts correct.  `$` applies to the whole operand, not the label name.  I'd figured this out not long ago, but apparently still hadn't grokked it.