# "8086 Assembly: Interpretation of 'AB' in Expression with A=2 and B=3"

Tags: assembly, x86

WHILE TRYING TO SOLVE A PROBLEM

NOT SURE ABOUT THE CONCEPT|
I have an assembly language expression, AB - A, where A is equal to 2 and B is equal to 3. How would an 8086 assembler interpret the 'AB' portion of the expression? Would it treat it as A multiplied by B (resulting in 2 * 3 = 6) or as a single value 'AB' with a value of 23?

Comment: Likely neither of those. It would say `AB` symbol is not defined. Please specify what assembler you use and provide [mcve].

Comment: Gnerally assemblers don't deal with expressions at all, except constant expressions.  `AB - B` will almost certainly just be an error, regardless of what `A` and `B` are.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: Most assemblers let you define named constants, like `AB equ 456` / `A equ 2`.  In MASM-syntax assemblers, `A=2` is actually valid syntax for defining an assemble-time constant.  (Related: [Assembly - How to multiply/divide a constant by another constant in assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46869106))

Comment: @PeterCordes: right, but that is only for constant expressions.  You can't have non-constant expressions in general (you might be able to have expressions involving labels, but only if the result is a constant, eg difference between two labels)

Comment: @ChrisDodd: Yes, exactly.  This question is asking about "assembly language expressions", which means assemble-time constants.  That's a valid thing to ask about.  (Although I share your suspicion that it's not what they really meant to ask.)  Still, it's not correct to say "*`AB - B` will almost certainly just be an error, regardless of what A and B are.*" because most assemblers do have ways to define that.  And in some, like NASM, that exact syntax will subtract two addresses if they're labels instead of numeric constants.  In a context like `dw AB - A` rather than immediate, also for MASM.

Comment: In most of computer science, multiplication is represented by an operator, usually `*` rather than as juxtapositioning used by math.  So, `AB` from math would be `A*B` in computer science syntax, and `AB` taken in computer science would simply be an identifier having 2 letters, and no relation to `A` or to `B`.